# What bundles include after Webpack and React-Lazy Code Splitting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

I am new using webpack so I dont understand very well how it works.

I have split my main bundle in different smaller files using webpack and React.Lazy in the imports.

After the build process, all works well and generate all these files:

[image]

Now, my problem is, that **I have only one entry point to my App: index.html**

What .js file I have to include in the index.html?

If I only include this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="./js/vendors~main.js"></script>
```

I have an error running my app:

```
VM6636 vendors~main.js:22 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(error: file:///*********************/dist/0.js)
```

Before Code Splitting, I had only two different files: main.js and vendors-main.js so at my index.html imported both.

Thanks in advance!!!

--

*If its important, this is my Webpack.config.js*

```
  plugins: [

     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     filename: '../index.html',
     template: './src/index.html'
     }),
    ]

}
```

Comment: We'd really need to see how you have webpack set up, as the answer to your question depends entirely on how you have it configured.

Comment: I have just added the webpack config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to instruct your `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to insert the required initial chunks into the `index.html` file with the [inject option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).

```js
// webpack.config.js

// ...

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: '../index.html',
  template: './src/index.html',
  inject: true
}),
```

This means you can remove the bundled `<script>` tag(s) from your `index.html` template, since the plugin will handle it for you.